# Using R in html

Tags: html, r

I want to use R language in HTML. Is there any R library or other method so I can put graph created by R in html page?
R will create the graph and then those graph should be shown in html page. It is a continuous process (i.e. r will continuously create graph and html will use them.)

Comment: Have you looked at `knitr` yet?

Comment: Try rpublisher : http://code.google.com/p/rpublisher/

Comment: If it needs to be interactive, try Shiny.

Comment: +1 for shiny, no question.

Comment: Check out the [shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/) package.
very good tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To embed charts (and `R` code) into a simple `html` page just use `knitr` as suggested in the above comment. But if you need something more try `Rook` which is a web server interface for `R`. You'll be able not just to put chart and code but also to make the user able to send requests to `R` (and get the responses, e.g. re-plot a chart, display different variables, etc). Basic 'getting started' [here](http://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/post/33814488298/deploy-rook-apps-part-ii)

Another package I am just looking at now is [hwriter](http://journal.r-project.org/2009-1/RJournal_2009-1_Pau+Huber.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to export graph to a ftp location from where your webpage is sourcing it's graph. I already using same solution just for private use, I export png to google drive subdirectory on my computer, google drive application sync it automatically to cloud space.